# All possible paths from one set of numbers to another

Tags: python

I would like to find all possible paths from [0,0,0,0,0,0] to [1,1,1,1,1,1]. So for example:

```
path_i = [[0,0,0,0,0,0], 
          [0,1,0,0,0,0],
          [0,1,1,0,0,0], 
          [0,1,1,0,0,1], 
          [0,1,1,1,0,1],
          [0,1,1,1,1,1],
          [1,1,1,1,1,1]]
```

would be one example of this possible path.

I can imagine some really horrible ways of doing this (randomly adding 1 to each list item where it is zero and iterating until you have all the unique paths). However, I believe there must be a better method

Edit: Asked for clarification of a step in each path

Where the sum of the subsists changes by 1, e.g.

```
 [0,0,0,0,0,0] -> [0,0,0,0,1,0] is a step

 [0,0,0,0,0,0] -> [0,0,1,0,1,0] is NOT a step
```

In each path, there should only be 7 steps

Thanks in advance
J

Comment: Define a "step" in your "path".

Comment: Then generate all possible steps from the given state and use your favorite tree traversing algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you agrre we have `7!` ways to find a path, you can use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) for that:

```
from itertools import permutations
paths = permutations(range(7), 7)

list_paths = []

for path in paths:
    tmp = [0]*7
    list_path = [tmp[:]]
    for index in path:
        tmp[index] = 1
        list_path.append(tmp[:])
    list_paths.append(list_path)
```

All yours paths are in `list_paths`

Comment: Thanks, a lot quicker and neater than what i had in mind!